# How can I stop a specific page in the Omega Responsive theme from being responsive

Tags: theming

I need to stop a specific page from resizing and display the styles specified in the normal stylesheet. I have an iframe that is a set width and height and will not display properly when viewed on smaller screen sizes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) modules. Delta was developed by the Omega developers and Context+Delta is part of the Omega philosophy.

Use Delta to create a variation on the original theme that does not respond to theme width.  Uncheck "Enable the responsive grid" setting in the theme, for instance. Then use Context to enable your Delta'd theme variation to trigger only on a certain path, in your case the page with the iframe.

Comment: Try this before attempting my solution...

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone can come up with a better option, I think you have two options.

One is to override the rules from the media queries in your `global.css` with a more specific one.  Pages should have a unique-enough class on them, eg `body.page-the-name-of-the-page` or `body.page-node-123`.

This is a really ugly solution, though.  Essentially, you would need to replicate one of the normal or wide sheets (eg, alpha-default-normal-16.css) in your `global.css` and prepend each and every selector with the body class.

The other option would be to implement a [hook_css_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7), check the page you are on, and remove the sheets you don't want.

Of the two, I would see if the `hook_css_alter` works in your situation.